Trigger a Composer DAG using Cloud Scheduler
I created a DAG in Composer that needs to be scheduled with custom params, possibly user-made params, more than 10 times a day. For that reason, that single DAG will be scheduled outside of Composer, and we want to use Google Cloud Scheduler to reach the Composer API to create the dag run.
When I deploy a Scheduler, I am unable to authentificate using OAuth token since the Composer URL doesn't end in "googleapis.com" (the URL being https://<id>-dot-<region>.composer.googleusercontent.com), and Scheduler doesn't allow that.
The only other option is OICD token, but I am unable to make it reach the webserver API, I always get a 401 error.
My service account has the permission to trigger the DAG, and I am able to trigger it using OAuth token and this code snipper (inspired by https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-3/access-airflow-api#make_calls_to_airflow_rest_api)
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

service_account_path = '####'
AUTH_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json.load(open(service_account_path)), scopes=[AUTH_SCOPE])

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(CREDENTIALS)

web_server_url = "####"
dag_id = '####'
params = {}


url = f'{web_server_url}/api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns'
response = authed_session.request(url=url, method='POST', json=params)
print(response.text)

And I got the result:
{
  "conf": {},
  "dag_id": "####",
  "dag_run_id": "manual__2024-07-09T09:51:10.605461+00:00",
  "data_interval_end": "2024-07-09T09:51:10.605461+00:00",
  "data_interval_start": "2024-07-09T09:51:10.605461+00:00",
  "end_date": null,
  "execution_date": "2024-07-09T09:51:10.605461+00:00",
  "external_trigger": true,
  "last_scheduling_decision": null,
  "logical_date": "2024-07-09T09:51:10.605461+00:00",
  "note": null,
  "run_type": "manual",
  "start_date": null,
  "state": "queued"
}

So the SA got the right priviledge, and is working correctly using OAuth token. Can you help me make it work with Cloud Scheduler?

Can you share the configurations you have selected in your cloud Scheduler?
